# How to manage css left property for fixed div

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I have div inside a div (`.konteineris2` and `.feedback`). When I use `left:-200px` in `.feedback` class, fixed div suddenly appears in the very left side of screen, outside `.konteineris2`. All I wanted it to move for 200px to the left outside `.konteineris2`, but not appear to the left screen border and then move 200px from that point.

HTML:

```
<div class="konteineris2">
   <div class="feedback">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.feedback{
   position:fixed;
   top:220px;
   width:100px;
   height:200px;
   background:white;
}
.konteineris2{
   width: 960px;
   height:700px;
   position:absolute;
   top:460px;
   padding-top:30px;
   pointer-events:none;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Any ideas how to manage it?

Comment: A working example would be helpful. Have you tried to use "position: relative" instead of an "absolute"?

Comment: Pls http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: just use `left:220px` for the outer div `.konteineris2` instead of the inner div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;` in `.konteineris2`

Add `margin-left: -200px;` in `.feedback`

Check it on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/rexmizan/full/gbqkp) . I think you're looking for the same thing.

Comment: Rats, why do I always assume they've used absolute on purpose?  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the context in which this occurs I'd guess the following might achieve your goal: Try adding `margin-left:-200px` instead.